# how to push multi values to array from single string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, arrays

I have a div under this ID "DivMarkers",which contains the values below :

```
["first Project","29.3619524","47.922233","4","1","Complated","green"," "],
["Second Project","29.3619524","47.922233","4","1","Complated","green"," "],
["Third Project","29.3619524","47.922233","4","1","Complated","green"," "]
```

and I am trying to push each line as an Array item to my array which is markers1

I need to make this using pure javascript without jQuery, I have tried this but it did not work :

```
var values = (document.getElementById('<%= Markers.ClientID %>').innerHTML);

markers1.prototype.push.apply(Array, values);
```

any suggestions to fix this? or can I just convert the upper string to Multidimensional Array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, using the below two lines :

```
var values = (document.getElementById('<%= Markers.ClientID %>').innerHTML);
markers1 = JSON.parse("[" + values +"]");
```

Thanks, everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

assuming that its containing a string, you do

```js
let array = document.querySelector("#divId").innerHTML.split("\n")
```

`.split("\n")` will return an array containing every new line

Comment: thanks for your helo the answer was to use JSON parser

Comment: guess you could do that too